# Understanding how to apply dominant balance method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have the differential equation
$$
\epsilon y'' - x^2 y' - y = 0
$$
and I want to test if there is a boundary layer at $x = 1$ for $\epsilon \ll 1$.

I started with the rescaling
$$
u = \dfrac{x - 1}{\delta}\ ,\qquad \delta = \delta(\epsilon)
$$
which gives me the differential equation
$$
\dfrac{\epsilon}{\delta^2} Y'' - \dfrac{1}{\delta}Y' - 2uY' - \delta u^2 Y' - Y = 0
$$
where $Y$ is now a function of $u$.

Now I'm supposed to apply a dominant balance argument to get $\delta(\epsilon)$, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm used to apply dominant balance with three terms, such that I can guess two of them are of the same order and much greater than the third one. This usually leads to one consistent relation that gives the expression for $\delta(\epsilon)$. However, this equation presents 5 different terms, and I'm not sure how I should proceed to make such comparisons. Should I compare two against the others, four against one, ...

Answer (score 1):

One method is to assume a power relation $\delta = \epsilon^\alpha$ and assume all other coefficients are order 1. This leads to five terms to play with
$$ \epsilon^{1-2\alpha}, \epsilon^{-\alpha},1,\epsilon^\alpha,1. $$
As you mentioned, you have more freedom and what you choose is up to you. Follow through on each to see how it behaves.

**Case 1:** Balance the first two - This leads to $\alpha = 1$ and the first two terms dominate (some exponential decay).

**Case 2:** Balance first and third - This leads to $\alpha = 1/2$ and the second term dominates ($Y \sim const.$ in this scaling).

**Case 3:** Balance first and fourth - This leads to $\alpha = 1/3$ and similar behavior as case 2.

Are there any other cases?

Comment: Case 2 is impossible as the second term $ϵ^{-1/2}$ would be large, similar with case 3.

Comment: I do say that... (the second term dominates).

Comment: I wouldn't say it is "impossible" - just not necessarily a helpful rescaling.

Comment: Of course, not impossible in the sense of "can't be done", but in the sense of "getting a balance". As a minimum, all balanced terms need be bounded for $ϵ\to 0$ (if necessary after rescaling the equation), and you want at least two terms that do not converge to zero, as one term alone can not be "in balance".